# 16.04 upgrade from 15.10 pkgs being removed instead of upgraded

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

Trying to upgrade twice now, but failed:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This can be caused by:  * Upgrading to a pre-release version of
Ubuntu  * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu  *
Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command
'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

In review of the upgrade "apt.log" the upgrade script appears to be removing packages as opposed to upgrading them.  i.e.: perl-modules is being removed as opposed to upgrading to perl-modules-5.22.

If I am reading this incorrectly, please advise or put me in the correct direction.

SC

--apt.log  (list of broken items)--

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 29 Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 29 Investigating (0) perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( perl ) (< 5.22.1~)
Considering perl-modules:amd64 -2 as a solution to perl-base:amd64 5475
Added perl-modules:amd64 to the remove list Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 5.22.1~)
Considering perl-modules:amd64 -2 as a solution to perl-base:amd64 5475
Added perl-modules:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing perl-base:amd64 via remove of perl-modules:amd64
MarkDelete perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( perl ) FU=0
Fixing perl-base:amd64 via remove of perl-modules:amd64 Investigating (0) findutils [ amd64 ] < 4.4.2-9build1 -> 4.6.0+git+20160126-2 > ( utils ) Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 0 as a solution to findutils:amd64 5103
Added libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing findutils:amd64 via remove of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
MarkDelete libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libgnome-desktop-3-12 [ amd64 ] < none -> 3.18.2-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) Broken libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 Breaks on libgnome-desktop-3-10 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.2-2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Considering libgnome-desktop-3-10:amd64 -3 as a solution to libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 53
Added libgnome-desktop-3-10:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 via remove of libgnome-desktop-3-10:amd64
MarkDelete libgnome-desktop-3-10 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.2-2ubuntu2 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libmwaw-0.3-3 [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.3.7-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) Broken libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 Conflicts on libmwaw-0.3-3v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.3.5-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Considering libmwaw-0.3-3v5:amd64 -3 as a solution to libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 10
Added libmwaw-0.3-3v5:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 via remove of libmwaw-0.3-3v5:amd64  MarkDelete libmwaw-0.3-3v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.3.5-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libodfgen-0.1-1 [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.1.6-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) Broken libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 Conflicts on libodfgen-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.4-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Considering libodfgen-0.1-1v5:amd64 -3 as a solution to libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 10
Added libodfgen-0.1-1v5:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 via remove of libodfgen-0.1-1v5:amd64
MarkDelete libodfgen-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.4-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) unity-control-center-faces [ amd64 ] < none -> 15.04.0+16.04.20160413-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome ) Broken unity-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.16.3-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Considering gnome-control-center-shared-data:amd64 -3 as a solution to unity-control-center-faces:amd64 9
Added gnome-control-center-shared-data:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing unity-control-center-faces:amd64 via remove of gnome-control-center-shared-data:amd64
MarkDelete gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.16.3-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libqca2 [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.1.1-2ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs ) Broken libqca2:amd64 Conflicts on libqca2v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.0-0ubuntu10 > ( libs )
Considering libqca2v5:amd64 -3 as a solution to libqca2:amd64 4
Added libqca2v5:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libqca2:amd64 via remove of libqca2v5:amd64
MarkDelete libqca2v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.0-0ubuntu10 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) unity-lens-music [ amd64 ] < 6.9.0+15.04.20141219-0ubuntu1 -> 6.9.1+16.04-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) Broken unity-lens-music:amd64 Conflicts on unity-scope-musicstores [ amd64 ] < 6.9.0+15.04.20141219-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Considering unity-scope-musicstores:amd64 -3 as a solution to unity-lens-music:amd64 4
Added unity-scope-musicstores:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing unity-lens-music:amd64 via remove of unity-scope-musicstores:amd64
MarkDelete unity-scope-musicstores [ amd64 ] < 6.9.0+15.04.20141219-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libvoikko1 [ amd64 ] < none -> 4.0.1-3ubuntu1 > ( libs ) Broken libvoikko1:amd64 Conflicts on libvoikko1v5 [ amd64 ] < 3.7.1-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Considering libvoikko1v5:amd64 -3 as a solution to libvoikko1:amd64 1
Added libvoikko1v5:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libvoikko1:amd64 via remove of libvoikko1v5:amd64
MarkDelete libvoikko1v5 [ amd64 ] < 3.7.1-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 0 as a solution to libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 1
Added libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 via keep of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
MarkKeep libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libmetacity-private3a [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:3.18.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) Broken libmetacity-private3a:amd64 Breaks on libmetacity-private3 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.17.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1:3.18)
Considering libmetacity-private3:amd64 -3 as a solution to libmetacity-private3a:amd64 1
Added libmetacity-private3:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libmetacity-private3a:amd64 via remove of libmetacity-private3:amd64
MarkDelete libmetacity-private3 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.17.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libjpeg-progs [ amd64 ] < 8c-2ubuntu8 -> 1:9b-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/graphics ) Broken libjpeg-progs:amd64 Conflicts on libjpeg-turbo-progs [ amd64 ] < 1.3.0-0ubuntu2 -> 1.4.2-0ubuntu3 > ( universe/graphics )
Considering libjpeg-turbo-progs:amd64 -1 as a solution to libjpeg-progs:amd64 0
Added libjpeg-turbo-progs:amd64 to the remove list
Conflicts//Breaks against version 1.3.0-0ubuntu2 for libjpeg-turbo-progs but that is not InstVer, ignoring
Fixing libjpeg-progs:amd64 via remove of libjpeg-turbo-progs:amd64
MarkDelete libjpeg-turbo-progs [ amd64 ] < 1.3.0-0ubuntu2 -> 1.4.2-0ubuntu3 > ( universe/graphics ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libcdr-0.1-1 [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.1.2-2ubuntu2 > ( libs ) Broken libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 Conflicts on libcdr-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Considering libcdr-0.1-1v5:amd64 -3 as a solution to libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 0
Added libcdr-0.1-1v5:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 via remove of libcdr-0.1-1v5:amd64
MarkDelete libcdr-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libcheese7 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) Broken libcheese7:amd64 Depends on cheese-common [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 -> 3.18.1-2ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (= 3.16.1-1ubuntu2)
Considering cheese-common:amd64 11 as a solution to libcheese7:amd64 -1
Removing libcheese7:amd64 rather than change cheese-common:amd64
MarkDelete libcheese7 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 -> 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10)
Considering tzdata:amd64 37 as a solution to tzdata-java:amd64 -1
Removing tzdata-java:amd64 rather than change tzdata:amd64
MarkDelete tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libwpd-0.10-10v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.10.0-2ubuntu4 > ( libs ) Broken libwpd-0.10-10v5:amd64 Depends on libwpd-0.10-10 [ amd64 ] < 0.10.0-2ubuntu4 -> 0.10.1-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.10.0-2ubuntu4)
Considering libwpd-0.10-10:amd64 7 as a solution to libwpd-0.10-10v5:amd64 -2
Removing libwpd-0.10-10v5:amd64 rather than change libwpd-0.10-10:amd64
MarkDelete libwpd-0.10-10v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.10.0-2ubuntu4 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) xserver-xorg-input-mouse [ amd64 ] < 1:1.9.1-1 > ( x11 ) Broken xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-21 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Considering xserver-xorg-core:amd64 41 as a solution to xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 -2
Removing xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 rather than change xorg-input-abi-21:amd64
MarkDelete xserver-xorg-input-mouse [ amd64 ] < 1:1.9.1-1 > ( x11 ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libperl5.20 [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) Broken libperl5.20:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (= 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2)
Considering perl-base:amd64 5475 as a solution to libperl5.20:amd64 -2
Removing libperl5.20:amd64 rather than change perl-base:amd64
MarkDelete libperl5.20 [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libcheese-gtk23 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) Broken libcheese-gtk23:amd64 Depends on libcheese7 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Considering libcheese7:amd64 -1 as a solution to libcheese-gtk23:amd64 -2
Removing libcheese-gtk23:amd64 rather than change libcheese7:amd64
MarkDelete libcheese-gtk23 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) postgresql-9.4-pgpool2 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.4-1 > ( database ) Broken postgresql-9.4-pgpool2:amd64 Depends on libpgpool0 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.4-1 -> 3.4.3-1 > ( universe/database ) (= 3.3.4-1)
Considering libpgpool0:amd64 1 as a solution to postgresql-9.4-pgpool2:amd64 -2
Removing postgresql-9.4-pgpool2:amd64 rather than change libpgpool0:amd64
MarkDelete postgresql-9.4-pgpool2 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.4-1 > ( database ) FU=0 Investigating (0) libhunspell-1.3-0v5 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.3-3ubuntu3 > ( libs ) Broken libhunspell-1.3-0v5:amd64 Depends on libhunspell-1.3-0 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.3-3ubuntu3 -> 1.3.3-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 1.3.3-3ubuntu3)
Considering libhunspell-1.3-0:amd64 35 as a solution to libhunspell-1.3-0v5:amd64 -2
Removing libhunspell-1.3-0v5:amd64 rather than change libhunspell-1.3-0:amd64
MarkDelete libhunspell-1.3-0v5 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.3-3ubuntu3 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (0) checkbox-ng-service [ amd64 ] < 0.20.1-1 > ( utils ) Broken checkbox-ng-service:amd64 Depends on checkbox-ng [ amd64 ] < 0.20.1-1 -> 0.23-2 > ( utils ) (= 0.20.1-1)
Considering checkbox-ng:amd64 0 as a solution to checkbox-ng-service:amd64 -2
Removing checkbox-ng-service:amd64 rather than change checkbox-ng:amd64
MarkDelete checkbox-ng-service [ amd64 ] < 0.20.1-1 > ( utils ) FU=0 Investigating (1) findutils [ amd64 ] < 4.4.2-9build1 -> 4.6.0+git+20160126-2 > ( utils ) Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 0 as a solution to findutils:amd64 5103
Added libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing findutils:amd64 via remove of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
MarkDelete libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (1) openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java )
Considering tzdata-java:amd64 -1 as a solution to openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 2
Added tzdata-java:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 via keep of tzdata-java:amd64
MarkKeep tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) FU=0 Investigating (1) libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 0 as a solution to libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 1
Added libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 via keep of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
MarkKeep libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (1) tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 -> 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10)
Considering tzdata:amd64 37 as a solution to tzdata-java:amd64 -1
Removing tzdata-java:amd64 rather than change tzdata:amd64
MarkDelete tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) FU=0 Investigating (2) findutils [ amd64 ] < 4.4.2-9build1 -> 4.6.0+git+20160126-2 > ( utils ) Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 0 as a solution to findutils:amd64 5103
Added libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing findutils:amd64 via remove of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
MarkDelete libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (2) openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java )
Considering tzdata-java:amd64 -1 as a solution to openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 2
Added tzdata-java:amd64 to the remove list
Fixing openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 via keep of tzdata-java:amd64
MarkKeep tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) FU=0 Investigating (2) libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 5103 as a solution to libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 1
Removing libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 rather than change libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
MarkDelete libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (2) python3.4 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) Broken python3.4:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Considering libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 5103 as a solution to python3.4:amd64 -1
Removing python3.4:amd64 rather than change libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64  MarkDelete python3.4 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (2) python3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) Broken python3.4-minimal:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 5103 as a solution to python3.4-minimal:amd64 -1
Removing python3.4-minimal:amd64 rather than change libpython3.4-minimal:amd64  MarkDelete python3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) FU=0 Investigating (2) tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 -> 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10)
Considering tzdata:amd64 37 as a solution to tzdata-java:amd64 2
Removing tzdata-java:amd64 rather than change tzdata:amd64
MarkDelete tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java ) FU=0 Investigating (2) libpython3.4 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( libs ) Broken libpython3.4:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Considering libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 5103 as a solution to libpython3.4:amd64 -2
Removing libpython3.4:amd64 rather than change libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64
MarkDelete libpython3.4 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0 Investigating (3) openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java )
Considering tzdata-java:amd64 37 as a solution to openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 2
Removing openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 rather than change tzdata-java:amd64
MarkDelete openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) FU=0 Investigating (3) openjdk-7-jre [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) Broken openjdk-7-jre:amd64 Depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) (= 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
Considering openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 37 as a solution to openjdk-7-jre:amd64 -1
Removing openjdk-7-jre:amd64 rather than change openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
MarkDelete openjdk-7-jre [ amd64 ] < 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( java ) FU=0 Done
MarkInstall ubuntu-desktop [ amd64 ] < 1.341 -> 1.361 > ( metapackages ) FU=1
ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on gnome-screensaver:amd64
```